# append column from file to another, awk

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to append `$1` in `file` to `$2` in `out` seperated by a `tab` while keeping the header row in `out`. The last line in `file` is duplicated in `out` and im not sure why that is? Thank you :).

**file**

```
/path/to/00-0000-000-xx-yyy
/path/to/01-1212-1111-aa-bb
```

**out** `tab-delimited`

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
1
2
```

**current**  `tab-delimited`

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 /path/to/00-0000-000-xx-yyy
1a1 /path/to/01-1212-1111-aa-bb
2a2 /path/to/01-1212-1111-aa-bb
```

**desired**  `tab-delimited`

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
1   /path/to/00-0000-000-xx-yyy
2   /path/to/01-1212-1111-aa-bb
```

**awk**

```
awk '{getline l < "file"; print $0"\t"l} ' FNR==1 out > tmp && mv tmp out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1; next} FNR>1{$0=$0 "\t" a[FNR-1]} 1' file out
Header1 Header2 Header3
1       /path/to/00-0000-000-xx-yyy
2       /path/to/01-1212-1111-aa-bb
```

The last line from `file` in your example is duplicated in `out` because when `getline` fails due to trying to read the 3rd line of a 2-line file it doesn't assign anything to `l` and so when it's printed `l` retains the last value for which `getline` succeeded. Read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're ever considering using getline again in future - it's rarely the best approach and when you do use it you have to use it in a very specific way as described in that article to guard against often cryptic and silent errors.

Also - never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} FNR==NR{if(FNR==1){print;next}a[FNR-1]=$0;next} {print a[FNR],$0}' out file
```

OR a non-one liner form of solution is as follows:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
FNR==NR{
  if(FNR==1){
    print
    next
  }
  a[FNR-1]=$0
  next
}
{
  print a[FNR],$0
}' out file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
1   /path/to/00-0000-000-xx-yyy
2   /path/to/01-1212-1111-aa-bb
```

Comment: Thank you both very much for the help and explanation :).